# How to consume my WCF service from my Android app without http://tempuri.org/?

Tags: android, web-services

I created a WFC service long time ago and I was accessing it from my Android app upload to Google Play.
Everything was working fine, but I suddenly got a message from Google telling me that they **REMOVED** my app from Play Store.
To make a long story short, they say:

> Your app is uploading users' information to http://tempuri.org

To communicate from my Android app to the WCF service I use a code I found long time ago in the Internet. I am not very savvy about all this, but it works correctly. For some reason that code access "tempuri.org" which is something about Microsoft. I have tried to remove that url from my code but I have no success.

This is how I access my service:

```
String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/" + METHOD_NAME;
String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

int SOAP_VERSION = SoapEnvelope.VER11;
String URL = "https://MyOwnUrl.com:444/Service1.svc";
try {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("OneParameter", "This is a text parameter");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SOAP_VERSION);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    Object result = envelope.getResponse();
    String resultData = result.toString();
    return resultData; <-- This works correctly, but why do I need tempuri.org?
} catch (IOException e) {  
    
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {  
    
}
```

This works correctly, but why do I need tempuri.org?

Answer (score 0):

Tempuri.org is the namespace that Microsoft sets in your WCF services by default. Then, if you public your web service without changing it, you will see that clients need to access it using that namespace.

So, it is always good to change it to another namespace. I cannot understand why the IDE doesn't ask you for a name and does it automatically. You have to do it manually. I followed the instructions [here](http://blog.rebuildall.net/2010/11/10/WCF_service_namespaces).
If you follow those instructions you could rename the namespace. Im my case, I didn't have to change the last part called "The binding". I don't know the reason, but if changed the bindings then nothing worked.

I hope I can change my code, upload it to Google Play and get accepted again.